# Camel SFTP file polling synchronize

Tags: apache-camel

We have SFTP polling consumer route to get files from SFTP server. Here is my problem, in the sftp server polling folder we have 100 of files but I want them to process in a bunch. Let's say my configuration maxMessagesPerPoll=10 then we would like to process these 10 files first then go for next round of fetching. But as of now, sftp consumer start consuming all the files and then processing it. Is there way to do this?
sftp.options: shuffle=true&moveFailed=../error/&preMove=../processing&delete=true&readLockLoggingLevel=INFO&maxMessagesPerPoll=10&delay=5000&disconnect=false&scheduledExecutorService=#sftpScheduledExecutor

```
from(getSftpOptions())
    .onCompletion()
    .onCompleteOnly()
        .process("routeCompleteProcessor")
        .log("Route processing is Completed ...")
        .end()
    .log("Starting the file process")
    .process("routeCBCheckProcessor")
    .unmarshal().gzipDeflater()
    .split(body().tokenizeXML("root", "*"),new SimpleStringAggregator()).streaming()
        .parallelProcessing(true)
        .process("lineProcessor")
    .end()
    .log("aggregate is completed...");
```

Comment: Could you please explain your problem more clearly?

Comment: Ok. Here is my scenario. I have 100 files in the SFTP server folder, and in my camel route i have configured to pull 10 files. As per my assumption what camel routing is doing is, it is taking 10 files and process it ( via the processor method), looks like even before the processor completes the task, the polling again happens and from sftp consumer. Is this correct assumption? or am i assuming wrong. All i wanted is, once camel consumer completes his 10 files then it has to go for next set of polling.

Comment: Try removing the `onCompletion()`